# UIView handle and pass touch events to next sibling view

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiview, uiscrollview

I'm building an iOS app that has a custom UIView upon a UIScrollView which in turn has a subview.

Here's the layout structure:

[image: layout structure]

Note that the custom UIView(called "Detected Object Hint View") is not a subview of ScrollView, it's a sibling view of UIScrollView. And I want to respond to tap gesture on the custom UIView, so I've added UITapGestureRecognizer to the UIView, and it works for tap, but the UIScrollView will never get any touch events (not responding to scroll or zoom gesture).

I've googled a while, and a lot of people pointed out that in order for other view to respond to the touch events, I should implement the following method:

```
- (id)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UIView *hitView = [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];
    if (hitView == self){
        return nil;
    }
    else {
        return hitView;
    }
}
```

But once I've added this method to my custom UIView, it will not respond to tap gesture either (of course).

So I'm wondering how can I handle the tap gesture on my custom UIView and pass the touch events to UIScrollView as well?

Big thanks!

Comment: may be you can try using notifications . I would suggest posting a notification from your scrollview to your custom view when you get a tap.

Comment: Do you really need another view? If you only want to recognize a tap why don't you just add the tap gesture to the scroll view?

Comment: @Priyatham51 actually, that's a great idea!

Comment: @Heliem I need to draw some stuff "over" the scrollview, are there any other ways I can achieve this?

Comment: you could draw your stuff and make that view setUserInteractionEnabled:NO. then you could add the gesture recognizer to the scroll view. But maybe @Priyatham51's way is better

Comment: Could you tell me which notification is?